# React with Node.js- Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs

I'm trying to learn React with node.js following an online tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm. When I run the Main.js I got the following error:`(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
  ....`

Here's the main.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And the app.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
     <div>
        Hello World!!!
     </div>
  );
  }
 }
export default App;
```

Webpack.config.js:

```
  var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
  path:'./',
  filename: 'index.js',
 },

 devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 8080
 },

 module: {
    loaders: [
       {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel',

          query: {
             presets: ['es2015', 'react']
          }
        }
    ]
  }
}
module.exports = config;
```

I searched for answers. Some said to use 'require' rather than import. I didn't quite understand how to use it or whether it's related to this issue. Can someone please help to explain? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: are u using babel?

Comment: @LucasKatayama Yes

Comment: could you post your webpack config?

Comment: try modifying the loader: `loader: 'babel-loader',`

Comment: @free-soul I tried. It still gives the same error

Comment: do you have the presets installed? `npm install babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015`

Comment: @free-soul Yea I have 3.10.8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129715/discussion-between-free-soul-and-user3735871).

Comment: In my projects I put the presets configs in .babelrc have you tried that?

Comment: Is this solved ?